# Remove quantity in the next object if first object quantity == 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My **Stock** model has `quantity` and `variant_id` attributes.

I add new stock once a week for a variant like so:

```
stock_1 = id: 1, variant_id: 1, quantity: 1, created_at:  Tue, 19 Feb 2019 15:19:00 UTC +00:00

stock_2 = id: 2, variant_id: 1, quantity: 3, created_at:  Tue, 26 Feb 2019 15:19:20 UTC +00:00

stock_3 = id: 3, variant_id: 1, quantity: 10, created_at:  Tue, 05 Mar 2019 15:19:39 UTC +00:00
```

When I sell an article, I want to remove it from the first stock where quantity is higher than 0.

I tried this method which almost do the job.

The problem is if I order 3 articles in the same variant:
3 quantity will be removed from stock_1
So the stock will be negative...

What would you suggest me to remove the rest from the  stock_2...

Is there a way to improve the idea?

```
@stock_1st = Stock.where(variant_id:1).where('quantity > 0').first

if @stock_1st.quantity == 0
  @stock_2nd = Stock.where(variant_id: item.variant_id).where('quantity > 0').first
  @stock_2nd.quantity -= item.quantity.to_i
  @stock_2nd.save
else
  @stock_1st.quantity -= item.quantity.to_i
  @stock_1st.save
end
```

## EDIT

thanks to  Aleksei Matiushkin for your precious help, but I am still having troubles

here the method:

```
 def remove_from_stock
  self.items.each do |item|
    Stock.where(variant_id: item.variant_id).where('quantity > 0').order(:created_at).reduce(item.quantity.to_i) do |quantity, stock|
      if leftover = item.quantity.to_i - stock.quantity <= 0
        stock.update_attributes! quantity: stock.quantity - item.quantity.to_i 
        break
      else
        stock.update_attributes! quantity: 0
        leftover
       end
      end
    end
   end
```

Did some more tests and I really have a problem: according to my example (which is above too).

My initial stock for `variant_id: 1`

```
stock_1 = id: 1, variant_id: 1, quantity: 1, created_at:  Tue, 19 Feb 2019 15:19:00 UTC +00:00

stock_2 = id: 2, variant_id: 1, quantity: 3, created_at:  Tue, 26 Feb 2019 15:19:20 UTC +00:00

stock_3 = id: 3, variant_id: 1, quantity: 10, created_at:  Tue, 05 Mar 2019 15:19:39 UTC +00:00
```

If I order 5 articles in this `variant_id: 1`

my remaining stock is 0 everywhere...

```
stock_1 = 0   #1/1 article is removed from this stock
stock_2 = 0   #3/3 articles are removed from this stock 
stock_3 = 0   #Only 1/10 should be removed, but stock.update_attributes!  set to quantity: 0
```

How can I fix this please?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ unless you explicitly sort the query, you might easily get `stock_3` as the first result of the query.

Comment: you are right thanks for pointing  this

Comment: one more comment, do not use things like `@stock_2nd.quantity -= item.quantity.to_i`, this can cause you problems in big projects, why ?, some one else might be buying the same variant, the code could load the same quantities for both requests which will lead to bad calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should retrieve the whole stockset and [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) it unless the whole quantity is distributed:

```
Stock.
    where(variant_id: item.variant_id).
    where('quantity > 0').
    order(:created_at).
    reduce(item.quantity.to_i) do |quantity, stock|

  if (leftover = quantity - stock.quantity) <= 0
    stock.update_attributes! quantity: stock.quantity - quantity
    break
  else
    stock.update_attributes! quantity: 0
    leftover
  end

end
```

Comment: Should also wrap it in a transaction, and raise if all stocks combined cannot fulfill the quantity.

Comment: @TamerShlash yep, indeed, but it’s unclear what to do in such a case and transaction would overcomplicate this already too multilined answer.

Comment: it says` undefined local variable or method `quantity' for #<Sale:0x007fd99651bab8>`my remove_from_stock method is in the Sale model

Comment: I was sure you could figure it out yourself. `item.quantity` or how is it called in your code. Updated the answer.

Comment: I am having troubles sorry, for example I order 2 articles, so it remove 1 article in in stock_1, and it removes 2 article in stock_2

Comment: No way. The code above removes exactly the requested amount.

Comment: Did some more tests and I really have a problem: according to my example, if i order 5 articles my `stock_1 = 0` i am ok ,` stock_2 = 0`I am ok,  but `stock_3= 0` I am not :) how can I fix this please?

Comment: The above perfectly answers the question stated. If you have any other questions, post other questions. Besides that, until you learn how to format text and use punctuation, I am unable to understand that gibberish.

Comment: Okay @Aleksei, I am sorry for my gibberish... I edited my question, let me know please if you can help on this one or if I 'd better ask a new question.

Comment: There is no way it removes all. Once again: the code above is correct. If you want me to troubleshoot anything, at least provide the info about starting conditions, quantity to remove etc. I am not a mind reader.

Comment: Parentheses are required, otherwise the `leftover` is assigned to the result of inequality. I have updated the answer. Also, while you copy-pasted my answer you made a mistake (probably you received an error back, induced by the lack of parentheses and blindly substituted `quantity` to `item.quantity.to_i` which makes zero sense.)

Comment: Sorry for blindly substituting, I am learning, and thanks for you help